# When did the API of apcu_cache_info() change, and how?

Tags: php, apcu

We're using [APCu](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) as a data cache for PHP on a number of different installations - workstations, development and production servers. Unfortunately, the APCu API appears to be a moving target, and there is little to no official documentation (that I could find). At the moment, we're getting quite different return values for `apcu_cache_info()`...

With APCu 4.0.1, an entry looks like this:

```
[
    'key' => 'the_entry_key',
    'atime' => 1450646021,
    'ctime' => 1450646021,
    'mtime' => 1450650861,
    'dtime' => 0,
    // ...
]
```

With APCu 4.0.7, it looks like this:

```
[
    'info'              => 'the_entry_key',
    'access_time'       => 1450650861,
    'creation_time'     => 1450646021,
    'modification_time' => 1450646021,
    'deletion_time'     => 0,
    // ...
]
```

According to the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/apc.php#L991), it now looks like this:

```
[
    'info'          => 'the_entry_key',
    'access_time'   => 1450650861,
    'creation_time' => 1450646021,
    'mtime'         => 1450646021,
    'deletion_time' => 0,
    // ...
]
```

We've seen other sudden API changes in the past, like when `apcu_sma_info()` and `apcu_cache_info()` had to be called with the string `"user"` as the first parameter - until they didn't. I understand that these changes are related in some way with keeping or dropping compatibility with the old APC extension, but it's getting a little hard to guess how to interact with APCu.

Are these changes documented somewhere, with a version number we can check against? Are there going to be any more changes to this in the near future? How can I get notified about them, other than seeing my application break?

The [documentation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-cache-info.php) has nothing to say about this, and neither does the project's [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/CHANGELOG) file. The PHP change log doesn't mention this as a backwards incompatible change either (probably because APCu isn't bundled with PHP by default).

Comment: Have you read this http://php.net/manual/en/apcu.installation.php about backward compatibitly mode

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, backward compatibility is a compile time option, and not enabled when APCu is installed as a package from a repository like Ubuntu's.

Comment: For history: That was changed in Oct 2014 [See this commit](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/commit/4f47d6dea51cf00ab13e623a6dd91c3d96c0fcc4). So 4.0.6 might be the last tag before the change. And was changed again [here](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/commit/c4b191c824d447b7d0639184be25fc2147bdb58c). Your best change might be to open an issue against the repository.

Comment: @Rangad  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I can confirm the first change for 4.0.7 and the second change for 4.0.8. Just my luck I had to hit a package with the "middle child" version :) ... If you like, copy your comment as an answer, then I can accept it and mark the question as answered.